# AVD Manager window blocks Eclipse window on Mac

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I'm a complete newbie trying to learn how to write an app. I'm trying to run Hello World using the emulator in Eclipse on my Mac. I launch and unlock the emulator. Android Training then implies that I should click the Run icon in Eclipse. But the ADT Manager window is in front of the Eclipse window and Eclipse is disabled. If I minimize the ADT Manager window it just quits the ADT Manager, and then I must close the emulator window.

I did discover that I can run the app with the Run button without starting the emulator as a separate step, although that takes a long time to get going.

Another Answer implies that I can just rerun the app by clicking the run button again, but I can't do this because the Eclipse window is disabled.

I'm used to being able to use the IDE while a program (Yes, I'm an old programmer) is running. What am I missing?

Duncan

Comment: After you close the AVD manager, why must you close the emulator? Can't you just minimize it instead? Or click on the Eclipse window to bring Eclipse forward? By the way, if you want to speed up the Emulator, run the Intel emulator. It's worth the extra hassle of installing it. Either that, or it's worth buying a cheap/used Android phone/tablet to test on (in case you don't have one already). Having a real device to test on is faster still than installing the Intel emulator.

Comment: Another thing you could do is to create and start the emulator before you run anything. The starting dialog that comes up when you do that allows you to reduce the relative size of the emulator window. This way, you can rearrange Eclipse to only take 3/4 of the screen real estate, and you can place the scaled down emulator window on the remaining part of the screen real estate which is not covered. That or better yet, you could connect a second monitor to your Mac (assuming you have one). This way, you could have Eclipse show on one screen and the emulator + logcat show on that second monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right - simply hitting run on the application cold turkey takes forever because the emulator has to initialize. When you click on your AVD Manager (where you can create, edit, and customize the android emulator you'd like to use), Select the emulator you'd like, then click Start.

After waiting for the emulator window to popup, just wait until the UI loads (when you can unlock the emulator).

At this point, it appears that the AVD Manager is still necessary (due to the "loading" type green bar along the bottom seemingly feeding the emulator), but you can just close the window, and the Eclipse window will become clickable again.

Now, you can just leave the emulator running. I typically leave it running for hours at a time (even overnight) and I can usually just click Run as Android Application and everything works perfectly.